# Django 2.1.7 get session key

Tags: python, django, session

I know this is a possible duplicate post, I found a solution for this, but those posts are from older versions of Django and I can't get the new syntaxis. Could someone give me a tip please?

I'm trying to prevent users to use the same account simultaneously. So when someone log in an account, if the user and pass are ok, I'm iterating the django_session table in order to find if theres any other session with the same account, if yes, close this session and start the last one.

After auth.authenticate(blah blah):

```
    if user is not None:
                # Checks if there's any other active session with the same account
                for session in Session.objects.filter(session_key=request.session.session_key): # //aq
                    data = session.get_decoded()
                    print(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))
                    if data.get('_auth_user_id', None) == str(user.id):
                    session.delete()
```

But something is not working with this syntaxis.
I can't get the session user's ID.
When a user logs in I'm using `request.session['logueado'] = user.id` and `auth.login(request, user)`.

This should be like a "last to log in wins" system.

EDIT: Whole code:

```
def login(request):
    if 'logged' in request.session:
        return redirect(main)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = LoginForm
        return render(request, "login.html", {"form": form})
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('POST method.')
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Valid form.')
            user_name = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            user_pass = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = auth.authenticate(username=user_name, password=user_pass)
            if user is not None:
                for session in Session.objects.filter(session_key=request.session.session_key):
                    print('Hello')
                    data = session.get_decoded()
                    if data.get('_auth_user_id', None) == request.session.session_key:
                        print('Same account in more than 1 session.')
                        session.delete()
                #------------------------------------------------------------------
                request.session['logged'] = user.id
                print(request.session['logged'])
                auth.login(request, user)
                request.session.set_expiry(0) #
                return redirect(main)
            else:
                return render(request, "loginError.html", {"form": form})
```

EDIT: Definitive solution: (Thank you Daniel Roseman!)

```
user = auth.authenticate(username=user_name, password=user_pass)
if user is not None:
    # Checks if there's another session with the same acc
    Sessions = Session.objects.all()
    for row in Sessions:
        print(row.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id'))
            print(user.id)
            if str(row.get_decoded().get("_auth_user_id")) == str(user.id):
                print('Same sessions')
                row.delete()

    request.session['logged'] = user.id
```

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi it is simply not deleting the duplicate session (older). It's not preventing anything. Both sessions can be at the same time

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. I'm loging in with the same account at it doesn't avoid it.

Comment: Nothing in any of this will have changed syntax between versions of Django.

Comment: My for loop is wrong, it is not iterating

Comment: Do you mean it's not executing at all, or it's only executing once?

Comment: Not executing at all. I've put a print('Hello') in the first line inside the loop and it is not printing it.

Comment: Are you definitely using the db session backend, rather than the file or cookie one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes I am. I've put the whole code if you want to check it, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is based on all sorts of false assumptions.

Session keys don't in any way map to login IDs. And they are unique: each client will have a different key, even if they're logged in as the same user. What's more, the session is explicitly flushed when a user logs in, so they will get a new key.

In other words, the only way to do something like this would be to iterate over *all* sessions in the database, decode them, and check if their `_auth_user_id` item is equal to the user ID.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, you're pointing me to the right direction. I editted my post in order to show how I figured this, I can't make it work yet though. If you want to check it... I would appreciate it

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? One thing I can see is that you haven't actually logged the user in yet, so `request.user.id` is None; you should compare against just `user.id`. Note also that this is likely to get fairly expensive once you have a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Roseman answered, you can iterate over *all* sessions in DB, decode all of them, and delete those you want. But it's slow, particularly if your site has high traffic and there are lots of sessions.

If you need a faster solution, you can use a session backend that lets you query and get the sessions of a specific user. In these session backends, Session has a foreign key to User, so you don't need to iterate over *all* session objects:

- [django-user-sessions](https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions) (based on django's `db` session backend)
- [django-qsessions](https://github.com/QueraTeam/django-qsessions) (based on django's `cached_db` session backend)

Using these backends, deleting all sessions of a user can be done in a single line of code:

```py
user.session_set.all().delete()
```

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of `django-qsessions`.